# Swiftで動画を撮りたい

Tags: swift, ios

Swiftで動画をとってUIImageViewに表示するプログラムを作成しました。しかし`CameraUtil`の`imageFromSampleBuffer`の1行目で`unexpectedly found nil`エラーが出てしまいます。

どのようにすればoutputからUIImageを取得することができるのでしょうか。

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var session : AVCaptureSession!
    var device: AVCaptureDevice!
    var output: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if self.initCamera(){
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func initCamera() -> Bool{
        self.session = AVCaptureSession()
        self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

        for device in devices{
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back){
                self.device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            }
        }
        if self.device == nil{
            return false
        }

        let input: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do{
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.device) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        }catch{
            return false
        }

        if self.session.canAddInput(input){
            self.session.addInput(input)
        }else{
            return false
        }

        self.output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        self.output.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        do{
            try self.device.lockForConfiguration()
            self.device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15)
            self.device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch{
            return false
        }

        let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", nil)
        self.output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        self.output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
            self.session.addOutput(self.output)
        }else{
            return false
        }

        for connection in self.output.connections{
            if let conn = connection as? AVCaptureConnection{
                if conn.supportsVideoOrientation{
                    conn.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didDropSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if sampleBuffer != nil{
               self.imageView.image = CameraUtil.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            }else{
                print("sample buffer is nil")
            }

        })
    }


}
```

**CameraUtil.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraUtil {
    class func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer)->UIImage{
        // サンプルバッファからピクセルバッファを取り出す
        let pixelBuffer:CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

        // ピクセルバッファをベースにCoreImageのCIImageオブジェクトを作成
        let ciImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

        //CIImageからCGImageを作成
        let pixelBufferWidth = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer))
        let pixelBufferHeight = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))
        let imageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,pixelBufferWidth, pixelBufferHeight)
        let ciContext = CIContext.init()
        let cgimage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: imageRect )

        // CGImageからUIImageを作成
        let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimage)
        return image
    }
}
```

ちなみに以下のサイトを参考にしています。

http://giveitashot.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2014/10/19/190505
http://qiita.com/koki_h/items/91d9bf918df7c5788ffc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたがリンクに挙げられている記事中では、`captureOutput(_:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)`メソッドは使ってないようです。

[`- captureOutput:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)

> *sampleBuffer*
>
> A `CMSampleBuffer` object containing information about the dropped frame, such as its format and presentation time..
>
> **This sample buffer contains none of the original video data.**

(太字部)**このサンプルバッファーは元のビデオデータを含んでいません。**

リンクに挙げられたサイト同様に`captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)`の方を使ってみるべきではないでしょうか?

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if sampleBuffer != nil{
           self.imageView.image = CameraUtil.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        }else{
            print("sample buffer is nil")
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。xcodeの補完を使っていたので違いに気が付きませんでした。

Comment: @StackDestroyer さん、解決の報告ありがとうございます。私自身も経験が山ほどあるのですが、コンパイルエラーの出ないミスは見つけにくいものです。説明不可能な挙動を見せるときは疑ってもいないところにミスがあるものなので、うまくコツをつかんで良いアプリを作ってください。